# жалуется на import Filter в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from aiogram import Filter  # <--
from aiogram import Command, CommandStart
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import TelegramObject
```

Comment: Что значит "жалуется"?

Comment: 1) Как именно жалуется? 2) Почему вы решили, что этот import вообще должен работать? 3) Вы явно поленились прочитать [справку по редактору](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: cannot import name 'Filter' from 'aiogram'

Comment: 2) Почему вы решили, что этот import вообще должен работать?

Answer (score 0):

Его можно получить из пакета `filters`

```py
from aiogram.filters import Filter
```